# Stubbing authentication in request spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, integration-testing, stubbing

When writing a request spec, how do you set sessions and/or stub controller methods?
I'm trying to stub out authentication in my integration tests - rspec/requests

Here's an example of a test

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../spec_helper'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/authentication_helpers'


describe "Messages" do
  include AuthenticationHelpers

  describe "GET admin/messages" do
    before(:each) do
      @current_user = Factory :super_admin
      login(@current_user)
    end

    it "displays received messages" do
      sender = Factory :jonas
      direct_message = Message.new(:sender_id => sender.id, :subject => "Message system.", :content => "content", :receiver_ids => [@current_user.id])
      direct_message.save
      get admin_messages_path
      response.body.should include(direct_message.subject) 
    end
  end
end
```

The helper:

```
module AuthenticationHelpers
  def login(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id # session is nil
    #controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(user) # controller is nil
  end
end
```

And the ApplicationController that handles authentication:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  helper_method :current_user
  helper_method :logged_in?

  protected

  def current_user  
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]  
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

Why is it not possible to access these resources?

```
1) Messages GET admin/messages displays received messages
     Failure/Error: login(@current_user)
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_helpers.rb:3:in `login'
     # ./spec/requests/message_spec.rb:15:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 106, accepted):

A request spec is a thin wrapper around [`ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/actionpack/3.0.7/ActionDispatch/IntegrationTest), which doesn't work like controller specs (which wrap [`ActionController::TestCase`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/actionpack/3.0.7/ActionController/TestCase)). Even though there is a session method available, I don't think it is supported (i.e. it's probably there because a module that gets included for other utilities also includes that method).

I'd recommend logging in by posting to whatever action you use to authenticate users. If you make the password 'password' (for example) for all the User factories, then you can do something like this:

```
def login(user)
  post login_path, :login => user.login, :password => 'password'
end
```

Comment: Thanks David. It works great, but it does seem to be a little overkill making all those requests?

Comment: If I thought it was overkill, I wouldn't have recommended it :)

Comment: It's also the simplest way to do it reliably. `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` is designed to simulate one or more users interacting via browsers, without having to use real browsers. There are potentially more than one user (i.e. session) and more than one controller within a single example, and the session/controller objects are those used in the last request. You don't have access to them before a request.

Comment: I have to use `page.driver.post` with Capybara

Comment: @IanYang `page.driver.post` may be an antipattern, according to Jonas Nicklas in [Capybara and testing APIs](https://www.varvet.com/blog/capybara-and-testing-apis/) )

Comment: I think, this one is good solution https://makandracards.com/makandra/37161-rspec-devise-how-to-sign-in-users-in-request-specs

Answer (score 65):

### Note for Devise users...

BTW, @David Chelimsky's answer may need a little tweaking if you're using [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).  What I'm doing in my integration / requests testing (thanks to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865555/how-to-do-integration-testing-with-rspec-and-devise-cancan)):

```
# file: spec/requests_helper.rb

# Rails 6
def login(user)
  post user_session_path, params: {
    user: {
      email: user.email, password: user.password
    }
  }
  follow_redirect!
end

# Rails 5 or older
def login(user)
  post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[email]' => user.email, 'user[password]' => user.password
end
```

Comment: when i then use 'login user1' in an rspec model spec, I get undefined local variable or method 'user_session_path' for #<RSpec::Core:

Comment: This assumes you have `devise_for :users` in `config/routes.rb` file.  If you've specified something different, you'll have to tweak your code accordingly.

Comment: This worked for me bu I had to modify it slightly. I changed `'user[email]' => user.email` to `'user[username]' => user.username` since my app uses username as a login instead of email.

Comment: You should use its `sign_in` test helper. You may find useful to pass in a user, to get control over `current_user` response in your controller. Example using a factory and a confirmed trait: let(:user) { create(:user, :confirmed) } before { sign_in(user) }. Dont forget to `include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers` ;)

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, in porting my Test::Unit tests to RSpec, I wanted to be able to login with multiple (devise) sessions in my request specs.  It took some digging, but got this to work for me.  Using Rails 3.2.13 and RSpec 2.13.0.

```
# file: spec/support/devise.rb
module RequestHelpers
  def login(user)
    ActionController::IntegrationTest.new(self).open_session do |sess|
      u = users(user)

      sess.post '/users/sign_in', {
        user: {
          email: u.email,
          password: 'password'
        }
      }

      sess.flash[:alert].should be_nil
      sess.flash[:notice].should == 'Signed in successfully.'
      sess.response.code.should == '302'
    end
  end
end

include RequestHelpers
```

And...

```
# spec/request/user_flows.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'User flows' do
  fixtures :users

  it 'lets a user do stuff to another user' do
    karl = login :karl
    karl.get '/users'
    karl.response.code.should eq '200'

    karl.xhr :put, "/users/#{users(:bob).id}", id: users(:bob).id,
      "#{users(:bob).id}-is-funny" => 'true'

    karl.response.code.should eq '200'
    User.find(users(:bob).id).should be_funny

    bob = login :bob
    expect { bob.get '/users' }.to_not raise_exception

    bob.response.code.should eq '200'
  end
end
```

**Edit**: fixed typo

Answer (score -1):

You could pretty easily stub the session as well.

```
controller.session.stub(:[]).with(:user_id).and_return(<whatever user ID>)
```

All ruby special operators are indeed methods. Calling `1+1` is the same as `1.+(1)`, which means `+` is just a method. Similarly, `session[:user_id]` is the same as calling method `[]` on `session`, as `session.[](:user_id)`

Comment: This seems like a reasonable solution.

Comment: This does not work in a request spec, but only in a controller spec.

Answer (score -3):

I found this very helpful for Devise : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)