# rspec & devise test helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, devise

According to [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-%28and-rspec%29) from the devise wiki I should be able to use a login_user helper method in my controller tests. Accordingly I have the following within the spec directory:

```
#spec_helper.rb
...
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
...
```

and

```
#support/controller_macros.rb
module ControllerMacros    
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      @user = Factory.create(:user)
      sign_in @user
    end
  end
end
```

however calling the helper doesn't work:

```
#requests/some_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe "GET /guides/edit" do
  login_user     
end
```

Can someone point toward where I'm going wrong. The test suite works about from this. I get a undefined local variable or method message so I guess the module isn't being included.

Rails 3.0.7
rspec 2.6.0
devise 1.3.4

[backtrace](http://www.pastie.org/2092178)

Comment: Is that a typo in your some_spec.rb? `log_in` / `login_user`

Comment: What's the backtrace you get?

Comment: Hi. Have added to foot of question.

Comment: hang on - that backtrace is saying it can't find you login_user method. I don't know what "controller_macros.rb" is... but how about just trying to put that straight into spec_helper.rb to see if login_user actually works... then figuring out how to include the ControllerMacros so that it can find your helper method.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I imagine there are a couple of problems with this approach. First is that you're using request specs, not controller specs, so the `login_user` method is not made available by `config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller`. Second, even if you are able to include the method it most likely won't work anyway, since the Devise test helpers are specifically written for controller/view tests, not integration tests.

Take a look at David Chelimsky's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787409/stubbing-authentication-in-request-spec/5803121#5803121) to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787409/stubbing-authentication-in-request-spec), which may be of help.

Comment: Thanks zetetic. You're completely correct, I was confusing controller and request specs. The linked answer works perfectly.

Comment: How to sign_out of logged in session in specs.

Answer (score 4):

I can't answer for sure... but the code smell for me is the "before(:each)" defined inside the helper. why don't you try:

```
#support/controller_macros.rb
module ControllerMacros    
  def login_user
    @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
    @user = Factory.create(:user)
    sign_in @user
  end
end
```

and

```
#requests/some_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe "GET /guides/edit" do
  before(:each) do
    login_user     
  end
end
```

and if that fails - maybe it just can't find @request - in which case, pass it as a variable to login_user

Edit:

Looks like you might need to include the devise test helpers.
The [rdoc](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) says you should have this file:

```
# spec/support/devise.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
end
```

Not sure if that differs from how you've already got it in spec_helper.rb
... looks pretty similar to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried that out but it's always the missing method variable/error which seems to suggest the module isn't included at all.

Comment: Hmm - sorry - I use it with Test::Unit (though I use rspec on another project), so I'm only guessing... Perhaps you could require 'devise' in spec_helper.rb ?

Comment: Hi Taryn. Thanks for your advice but it does look like I was confusing controller specs and request specs.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with Rails 3.0.10 rspec 2.6.0 devise 1.3.4 spork-0.9.0.rc9 on my controller specs, i have changed `config. extend` to `config.include` and its work !

Answer (score 0):

Forget to confirm if your app is not confirmable. Your code should look like

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      #user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the confirmable module
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```