# NoMethodError: undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Authorization::WhenSignedIn::GETIndex:0x834c9d88>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

I try to sign in user  to test it in Rspec with Devise.
Right now I have:

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
sign_in user
```

And I get an error

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::Authorization::WhenSignedIn::GETIndex:0x8374cc2c>
 # ./spec/features/authorization_spec.rb
```

I have read some SO questions and some devise docs about testing(Like [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)))

So far I tried some various ways, but still didn't manage it to work.
If neccessary I can also list them here, but they tend to new errors and complications.
**So what do I do to make it all work?**

LONG STORY:
Things I have tried:

Trying something like this:

```
@user ||= FactoryGirl.create :user
post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[email]' => @user.email, 'user[password]' => @user.password
```

Adding to devise and rails_helper this lines:

```
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :controller
  config.include Devise::TestHelpers, type: :view
```

And other ways.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403650/rspec-devise-test-helpers?

Answer (score 0):

Finally works like this:

```
@user ||= FactoryGirl.create :user
page.driver.post new_user_session_path, 'user[email]' => @user.email, 'user[password]' => 'password123'
```

Thanks to @Arun Kumar