# How can I test a controller method that uses information from the current_user of Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, rspec-rails

I am trying to test a controller method that obtains the user_id from the current_user of devise.

Following other answered questions, I try to sign_in with the User mock_up but it gives me the same problem as in [undefined method `sign_in' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x1057fd428> error while trying to set up RSpec with Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141763/undefined-method-sign-in-for-rspeccoreexamplegroupnested-1nested-10/15400791#15400791). In that question, the accepted answer says that you can't use Devise helpers inside an rspec integration test.

Being this true, how can I test a controller method that needs a logged user to execute?

Comment: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Controllers-and-Views-tests-with-Rails-3-(and-rspec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you Mock the "current_user"? Since its from Devise, its already been tested... You should have no coverage problems mocking it with your User under test