# Session hash name error in integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, session, minitest

I'm trying to test with minitest two controller methods:

```
class CurrenciesController < InheritedResources::Base

  def mark_refresh
    session[:refreshable] = true
    redirect_to currencies_url
  end

  def unmark_refresh
    session[:refreshable] = false
    redirect_to currencies_url
  end
end
```

My test:

```
require "minitest_helper"

describe "Currencies integration" do

  it "should auto refresh" do
    visit currencies_path
    click_on "Auto refresh"
    session[:refreshable].must_equal true
  end

  it "should turn off auto refresh" do
    session[:refreshable] = true
    visit currencies_path
    click_on "Auto refresh"
    session[:refreshable].must_equal false
  end
```

but I'm getting *undefined local variable or method `session'*. Session hash must be initialized somehow in tests? I'm using rails 3.2.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned, that in integration tests session hash shouldn't be tested and it's not added by default there. 
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342355/session-available-in-some-rspec-files-and-not-others-how-come) was really helpfull to figure that out.