# Access session inside spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have this simple helper found at *spec/helpers/session.rb*:

```
def sign_in user
    session[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

However, I get an error when I try to use it in a spec. The following:

```
context 'when user is is signed in' do
    before do 
        sign_in user
        request 
    end

    specify{ expect(flash[:success]).to eq "Signed out successfully" }
end
```

gives me:

```
Failure/Error: sign_in user
NameError:
undefined local variable or method `session' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups::AdminArea::Authentication::GuestVisitsRoot:0x00000004f835f0>
```

So how can I manipulate the session from inside a spec? Is it possible?

Comment: Are you using rails or other web framework? If you tag your question more precisely, chances are you could get more help.

Comment: Good point, thanks. I'm on rails

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are seeing this error in integration test. Integration tests aren't designed for checking `session` related things.

You can achieve same thing in this way

```
def sign_in user
    # you can also use 
    # something like this 
    # post signin_path, :login => user.login, :password => 'password'
    # but i dont recommend this, since this is not how user do it.
    visit sign_in_path
    fill_in 'Email', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Sign in'
end
```

And then in test, something like

```
 expect(page).to have_content('My Account')
```

There are many great answer available . Have a look, if you have any problem..include it in question i will try to answer

1. [session available in some rspec files and not others. how come?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11342355/session-available-in-some-rspec-files-and-not-others-how-come)
2. [Stubbing authentication in request spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787409/stubbing-authentication-in-request-spec)
3. [End-to-End Testing with RSpec Integration Tests and Capybara](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara)

Comment: NOTE: `visit`, `fill_in`, and `click_button` are not rspec methods!! For that you'll need Capybara! OP has tagged just rspec and Ruby on Rails.

Comment: yes. I guess he forgot to get the tag. He didnt even added `rails` earlier.