# RSpec, authenticating Devise user in request specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, warden

I'm trying to write RSpec request specs in order to test my service API and for that I need the user to be authenticated.
I found some examples on the net but nothing works, for the moment I'm stuck with this:

```
require "spec_helper"

include Warden::Test::Helpers
Warden.test_mode!

describe "My requests" do

  it "creates an imaginary object" do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    login_as(user, :scope => :user)
    post "/my_service", :my_data=> {:some => "data"}
    expect(response.body).to include("success")
  end

end
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
 ArgumentError: uncaught throw :warden
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually sign in the user (i.e. the user needs to submit the login form, or at least do a POST on your login action) as explained here: [Stubbing authentication in request spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787409/stubbing-authentication-in-request-spec)

Comment: That is exactly what I'm trying to do using warden as you can see, to no avail.

Comment: The related answer helped me figuring out an alternative way that works, so thank you for that.

Comment: @AdnanDoric to know that you found a solution magically make my problems solve themselves. Awesome

Comment: @AdnanDoric if you could update your question with a few details that would be great. I am having the same issues here and any help would be great. I think that may be what Benjamin was getting at.

Answer (score 21):

It is simplest to just:

**spec/rails_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers, type: :request
end
```

And just use `sign_in` in your request spec. This is the equivalent of declaring `include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers` in an system/feature spec or Rails system/controller test.

Doing it this way leads to a 'better' test.

Comment: by applyting this solution im getting 
[#<Proc:0x00005624201db3f8@/home/humayun/.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/warden-1.2.9/lib/warden/test/helpers.rb:19>]