# How to do integration testing with RSpec and Devise/CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise, cancan

If I have a Devise model User, of which only those users with role :admin are allowed to view a certain url, how can I write an RSpec integration test to check that the status returns 200 for that url?

```
def login(user)
  post user_session_path, :email => user.email, :password => 'password'
end
```

This was pseudo-suggested in the answer to this question: [Stubbing authentication in request spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787409/stubbing-authentication-in-request-spec), but I can't for the life of me get it to work with devise.  CanCan is receiving a nil User when checking Ability, which doesn't have the correct permissions, naturally.

There's no access to the controller in integration specs, so I can't stub current_user, but I'd like to do something like this.

```
describe "GET /users" do
  it "should be able to get" do
    clear_users_and_add_admin #does what it says...
    login(admin)
    get users_path
    response.status.should be(200)
  end
end
```

**NOTE!!!**:  all this has changed since the question was asked.  The current best way to do this is here: http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

Comment: Note: all this has changed since the question was asked. The current best way to do this is here: http://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara Just to reiterate for first sigh readers like me

Answer (score 48, accepted):

@pschuegr's own answer got me across the line. For completeness, this is what I did that gets me easily set up for both request specs and controller specs (using FactoryGirl for creating the user instance):

in /spec/support/sign_in_support.rb:

```
#module for helping controller specs
module ValidUserHelper
  def signed_in_as_a_valid_user
    @user ||= FactoryGirl.create :user
    sign_in @user # method from devise:TestHelpers
  end
end

# module for helping request specs
module ValidUserRequestHelper

  # for use in request specs
  def sign_in_as_a_valid_user
    @user ||= FactoryGirl.create :user
    post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[email]' => @user.email, 'user[password]' => @user.password
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include ValidUserHelper, :type => :controller
  config.include ValidUserRequestHelper, :type => :request
end
```

Then in request spec:

```
describe "GET /things" do
  it "test access to things, works with a signed in user" do
    sign_in_as_a_valid_user
    get things_path
    response.status.should be(200)
  end
end

describe "GET /things" do
  it "test access to things, does not work without a signed in user" do
    get things_path
    response.status.should be(302) # redirect to sign in page
  end
end
```

and similarly, use 'signed_in_as_valid_user' in controller specs (which wraps Devise::TestHelpers sign_in method with a user from FactoryGirl)

Comment: I have defined the same modules as you mentioned, but I get this error ` undefined local variable or method `sign_in_as_a_valid_user' for #<Class:0x0000000559baa0> (NameError)`. Where am I making a mistake?

Comment: This is in a request spec, right? Is your `Rspec.configure` code executing?

Comment: Yes, this is in a request spec. How do I check whether the `Rspec.configure` code executes?

Comment: I'd put a breakpoint there if you can run your specs through an IDE with a debugger (like Rubymine) or try the `pry` gem, or a good ol' `puts "hello world"` in there :)

Comment: @MattConnolly, can you modify your answer to have `require 'spec_helper'` at the top of your request spec?

Answer (score 28):

Ah, so close.  This does the trick - I was missing the proper parameter form, and the redirecting.

```
post_via_redirect user_session_path, 'user[email]' => user.email, 'user[password]' => user.password
```

Comment: I had to use `page.driver.post` instead of `post_via_redirect` (request specs)

Comment: hey how can i user current_user in request spec test cases like how we use in controller spec test cases

Comment: I got the error `undefined local variable or method 'user_session_path'`

Comment: @Phifo For future references: You can use `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_session_path`    or `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` beforehand if you use this in place where url_helpers not accessible. 

But they should be included in tests by default though, as far as I know.

Answer (score 21):

I used a slightly different approach, using the Warden::Test::Helpers.

In my spec/support/macros.rb I added:

```
module RequestMacros
  include Warden::Test::Helpers

  # for use in request specs
  def sign_in_as_a_user
    @user ||= FactoryGirl.create :confirmed_user
    login_as @user
  end
end
```

And then included that in RSpec's config in spec_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include RequestMacros, :type => :request
end
```

And then in the request specs themselves:

```
describe "index" do
  it "redirects to home page" do
    sign_in_as_a_user 
    visit "/url"
    page.should_not have_content 'content'
  end
end
```

In contrast to the `post_via_redirect user_session_path` method, this actually works and allows me to use current_user in before_filters, for example.

Comment: Wiki article: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-with-Capybara

Answer (score 0):

You can create a macro (/spec/support/controller_macros.rb) and write something like :

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = :user
      @user = Factory(:user)
      sign_in @user
    end
  end
end
```

You can also include any CanCan attributes you want. Then, in your spec :

```
describe YourController do
    login_user

    it "should ..." do

    end
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Spyros, but it works fine in the controller using the Devise::TestHelpers.  It's just in the request specs it doesn't work (@request is nil).

Comment: You mention that you receive a nil user. This would mean that the spec does not login the user. Are you sure you use devise helpers and login correctly ? You can test that inside your spec to make sure. If not, you can try the code above. I think it all comes from the fact that your spec does not log in a user.

Comment: This answer is for controller testing, not integration testing, like the question was for - the comments about the nil user submmited by the asker is because the answer is for the wrong situation

Answer (score 0):

I found this link very helpful https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Test-controllers-with-Rails-3-and-4-(and-RSpec)

Answer (score 0):

As of mid 2017, we have one more, in my opinion better opprotunity to integrate devise in our Rspecs. We are able to utilize stub authentization with helper method `sign in` defined as described below:

```
module ControllerHelpers
    def sign_in(user = double('user'))
      if user.nil?
        allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_throw(:warden, {:scope => :user})
        allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(nil)
      else
        allow(request.env['warden']).to receive(:authenticate!).and_return(user)
        allow(controller).to receive(:current_user).and_return(user)
      end
    end
  end
```

You should also append in `spec_helper.rb` or `rails_helper.rb` reference to newly created file:

```
require 'support/controller_helpers'
  ...
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    ...
    config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
    config.include ControllerHelpers, :type => :controller
    ...
  end
```

Then in method just place at the beginning of the method body `sign_in` for context for authenticated user and you are all set. Up to date details can be found in devise docs [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Stub-authentication-in-controller-specs)