# Custom authentication: login helper for request specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to RSpec. I've created an authentication from scratch as described in [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1), I would like login code to run before some (not all) of my request (integration) specs.  I've thinking of the few solutions, but I wonder what's the best way to approach this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could try Matt Connoly's answer at [How to do integration testing with RSpec and Devise/CanCan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865555/how-to-do-integration-testing-with-rspec-and-devise-cancan).

Obviously you would need to rewrite the methods according to your authentication set-up, but it should get you going.